# How can I change IP in HttpServletRequest from client side?

Tags: java, security, ip, httprequest, spoofing

server code:

```
  String  ip =  request.getRemoteAddr()
     if(ip='127.0.0.1')
        System.out.print("hello");
```

Now I am accessing that remote site from my machine, so obvious my IP address should be like `192.*.*.*`.

How can I cheat the server(IP spoofing) so server always prints "hello" for my request?

Answer (score 1):

New answer to edited question:
You can't in Java. If need to pretend that the request is coming from 127.0.0.1 (the server itself), so you'll need to hack into the network stack of your operating system.

Old answer:
The IP Address your client uses to connect to the server depends on the network interface it uses and the kind of network attached to this network interface.
Example:
If your client is a laptop it most likely has only one network interface. This network interface uses 192.168.1.10 as its IP address (e.g., assigned from the DHCP on your router) as its internal IP address. Your router might also be connected to the internet, with an IP, say 20.20.20.20, which it shares with connected devices via NAT.
If you use this to connect to your server which is on your local network, the client's IP address that the server sees will be 192.168.1.10; if you connect to your server which is not on your local network but somewhere on the internet, your client's IP (that the server sees) will be 20.20.20.20

So you cannot make your client pretend to use 127.0.0.1 (if server and client are running on the same machine, your client will most likely have 127.0.0.1). Of course there are techniques like IP spoofing where you pretend to have a different IP than you actually have, but that's totally different issue.

Comment: ya actually i want to do IP spoofing.
On server side i have there one check like if IP is "192.168.xx.xx"
So how can i spoof that Ip even my IP is "192.168.yy.yy"

Comment: You will have to hack into your operating system's network stack to replace the sending IP with the one you want to spoof (in every IP packet's header). That does of course pose the problem of the client no longer getting responses from the server...

Comment: In short ,use like three-way handshake,So may i say is impossible to hack this ?

Comment: You cannot really defend against IP spoofing. If I pretend to be a packet from someone else, there is little you can do to notice that. This is why there are mechanisms like authentication (you ask me to prove that I am the one who I claim to be) and IPsec (VPN) where packet headers are signed to prevent tinkering. Handshakes are authentication-based mechanisms. Technically they do not prevent IP spoofing, but they let you notice.

Comment: I have edited my question . I want way to print `hello` any how .